# automate office 365 health checkup to take screenshot every hour

Tags: sharepoint-online, powershell, office-365, health-analyzer

So the requirement is like this:

1. Login to o365 portal, navigate to health section ( this url https://portal.office.com/AdminPortal/Home#/servicehealth)
2. take the screenshot of the page
3. upload the page in a sp lib/email it

Please suggest ways to accomplish this. I know how to write a script to take the screenshot, but not how to login in message center and upload the screenshot in sp lib.

Note: We have MFA enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you can do .

For accessing the information present in Message Center you need to **download Office 365 Service Communications Power Shell Module from Git Hub**.

Download the library, and un-zip the file

Now you will need to relocate the module files.

Follow this script below :-

Import-Module **Location where you have downloaded your files from git**

Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\SharePoint Online Management Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.dll"

Add-Type -Path "C:\Program Files (x86)\SharePoint Online Management Shell\Microsoft.Online.SharePoint.PowerShell\Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.Runtime.dll"

$User = "tenant.admin@company.onmicrosoft.com"

$Pass = "password"

$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($User,(ConvertTo-SecureString $Pass -AsPlainText -Force));

$MySession = New-SCSession -Credential $cred

$Events = Get-SCEvent -EventTypes Message -PastDays 10 -SCSession $MySession |
Select-Object Id, Title, StartTime, Service, EventType, Status, @{n='Message';e={$_.messages[0].messagetext}}

foreach ($Event in $Events)

{

$Event.Id
$Event.Title
$Event.StartTime
$Event.Message
$Event.Service
$Event.EventType
$Event.Status

}

Write-Host "Completed!"

This is the way i know to retrieve messages from Message center in O365 tenant.

Notes :- **Rather than taking a screenshot i would suggest above approach  . You can save this data in csv and maintain a csv date wise for your requirement.**